# Does SqlCommandParameter need SqlType to be set as SqlImage if value is bigger then 8KB?

Tags: sql-server, parameters

Long time back in past I had read somewhere that if we want to enter data in "image" typed field of table whose value is more then 8kb, then we must explicitly specify parameter type to SqlImage. Is this true? I don't find any such documentation about it anymore.

I tried to use Reflector to reverse engineer the SqlClient in order to see if it's required or not, but I didn't get any hint about it. If anyone can give me any confirmed statement that it's not necessary it will be of great help.

I am using SQL 2008 and I am using Image data type not varbinary or binary.

Comment: Recommend you retag this question. Its not so much about as it is about the software you are using to access the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of SQL Server are you working with?

Image is a soon to be deprecated data type. Use varbinary(max) instead.

From [SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx):

> This feature will be removed in a
>   future version of Microsoft SQL
>   Server. Avoid using this feature in
>   new development work, and plan to
>   modify applications that currently use
>   this feature. Use varchar(max),
>   nvarchar(max) and varbinary(max) data
>   types instead. For more information,
>   see Using Large-Value Data Types.